# How to check all years in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger:

```
alter trigger max_14_holidays
on contentment
after update,insert
as
    if exists(select employeeid
              from contentment
              where year (DateEnd) = 2018
                and absenteecat = 'holiday'
              group by employeeid
              having sum(datediff(day, DateStart, DateEnd) + 1) > 14)
    begin
         raiserror ('Already more than 14 days', 16,1)
         rollback transaction
    end
```

But this trigger is ONLY for 2018, I want to check it for every year that is in the database (`DateEnd`). How can I do this? I use SQL Server.

Comment: Just change `... where year(DateEnd)=sysdate`

Comment: @marc_s I say that I use SQL Server?

Comment: YOu should add this **as a `sql-server` tag**, too !

Comment: This trigger is missing a correlation to the actual rows affected. In this case once **any** employee hits 14 days, no other employee will be able to update or insert any rows in that table. You need to filter to only the `employeeid` values that are also found in the `inserted` pseudo-table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Could you be a little more specific? What would you change in the trigger then?

Comment: I think you need to better explain your business rules. Is it to ensure that no employee can take more than 14 consecutive days off, more than once, in any single year? What if someone takes off from Christmas to January 10th? The trigger as written does not make your rules clear and the query also checks the entire table, not just the current employee that triggered the trigger. We need the actual rules to help you write the proper logic.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Is it to ensure that no employee can take more than 14 consecutive days off, more than once, in any single year? > Yes, thats true. What if someone takes off from Christmas to January 10th? > I want to change the absenteecat later on to something that this could not occur. And the last comment from you, I dont understand? I check the employeeid?

Comment: You're checking the employeeid *in the table* but not the employeeid(s) referenced *in the trigger*. Think about it: you add a holiday for employeeid 5, the trigger fires, and your query asks literally: "Is there *any* employee in the table with a holiday more than 14 days?" This query does *not* restrict to employeeid 5, and so will roll the transaction back if *any* employee has a holiday that meets those rules. See [Example C in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) for how an `IF EXISTS` check also joins to `inserted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.max_14_holidays -- always use schema prefix
ON dbo.contentment
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.contentment AS c
      WHERE EXISTS 
      (
        SELECT 1 FROM inserted AS i 
          WHERE i.employeeid = c.employeeid 
          AND DATEPART(YEAR, i.DateEnd) = DATEPART(YEAR, c.DateEnd)
      )
      GROUP BY employeeid, DATEPART(YEAR, DateEnd)
      HAVING SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DateStart, DateEnd)+1) > 14
  )
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Already more than 14 days', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  END
END
```

Note that this will roll back the entire transaction even if you insert/update two employees in the same statement and one of them stays valid (<= 14 days) and one becomes invalid (> 14 days), even the same employeeid updating rows for multiple years where one years stays valid and a different year does not. And it doesn't log that anywhere, so there's no way to recover the valid data while rejecting the invalid data (unless you simply enforce that you can only ever insert/update one single employeeid + year combination at a time). Also, this doesn't check for overlapping ranges entered by mistake (e.g. someone takes off the 1st to the 10th and then the 7th to the 13th), nor does any of this account for weekends or holidays.

Comment: Okay, I have some questions: Why do you: 'Set Nocount On'? Also in my case you can't insert or update two employees at the same time. So the solution that this checks for every year it's where you use datepart?

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON` is a habit. It just prevents `DONE_IN_PROC` messages from the trigger getting sent to the caller. Maybe your app prevents two employees from being affected at a time, but does it prevent two rows from being affected? What about people who update the table directly (or exploits a bug in your app)? The datepart just makes sure that you're caring about existing holidays in the same year as the holiday you're inserting/updating.